# Как убрать названия вкладки chrome?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, chrome-extension

как можно убрать названия. Или хотя бы ограничить до 3 символов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно написать плагин, который убирает тайтл или ставит такой, который Вам надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете добавить такой код в functions.php вашей темы:

```
/**
 * Filters the document title before it is generated.
 *
 * @param string $title Page title.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function pre_get_document_title_filter( $title ) {
    $title  = mb_substr( $title, 0, 3 );

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', [ $this, 'pre_get_document_title_filter' ], 20 );
```

P.S. Хром берёт текст вкладки из тега `<title></title>`, а он формируется с помощью этого хука.

Comment: Мне не для сайта надо, мне для самого хрома) Я к примеру смотрю видео на ютуб, я не хочу видеть title вкладки( если она не активна)

Comment: Этот код формирует тот самый документ title, который попадает на вкладку Хрома